# Pandas function that won't return rows with blank date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe formatted like this in pandas.

```
(df)
ID     Num          Col 1        Col 2       Status       Date
1      6000TO6100   6000         6100        Active       2020-07-18
2      9-999        NaN          NaN         Active       2020-03-30
3      7000TO8000   7000         8000        Active       2020-07-18
4      9-999        NaN          NaN         Active       NaT
5      3800         NaN          NaN         Active       NaT
6      72-11        NaN          NaN         Active       2020-07-18

....
```

I made a function like this that will return the row of the input number depending on if a number is in the range of Col 1 and 2 and is also active. The problem is that for an input like 9-999 it will return

```
(df)
ID     Num          Col 1         Col 2        Status       Date
2      9-999        NaN           NaN         Active       2020-03-30
4      9-999        NaN           NaN         Active       NaT
```

But my desired output is

```
(df)
ID     Num          Col 1         Col 2        Status       Date
2      9-999        NaN           NaN         Active       2020-03-30
```

Here is my code:

```
search = " "

try:
    int(search)
    check_col = df.loc[(df['Col 1'] <= int(search)) &  (df['Col 2'] >= int(search)) & (df['Status'] == 'Active')]
    if len(check_col) > 0:
        print(check_col)

except:
    pass

check_num = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Active') & (df['ID'] == str(search))]

if len(check_num) > 0:
        print(check_num)
```

I need to edit this function so that empty values in the "Date" column don't get printed in the solution. I was thinking about making a date variable and saying if Date is > 0 then print along the lines of `(df['Date'] == 'NaT')` returns false but I'm not sure. I'm still kind of new with python so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dropna()` before you apply your code:

```
df = df.dropna(subset='Date')
```